# serial.Serial.readline() raises SerialException, but the same code worked a week ago

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pyserial

I have a pair of applications that communicate by sending text (in one direction only) over a serial port.  They have been working great for a while.  Last week the reading side stopped working *on my machine*, and raises a `SerialException` whenever I call the `readline()` method of my `serial.Serial` object.  *The same code works fine on another machine!*  The only thing I can think of that could have caused a problem is that I installed a bunch of system updates the night before this happened (Any idea how to see the history on *that*?).  I'm using Ubuntu and Python 2.7.6 (see below), and as far as I can tell I have the same python packages installed on both machines.

I've written two small sample apps to try to troubleshoot, and am getting the following error on the reading side:

```
File "./reader.py", line 16, in <module>
  s = port.readline()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 475, in read
  raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)')
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether I use a "real" port or a "virtual" port, so this can be reproduced by creating two virtual ports with the following command:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

Here is the sample "writer.py" that I created for troubleshooting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import serial

print( 'Opening port' )
port = serial.Serial( port='/dev/pts/5',  # Substitute the correct port here!
                      baudrate=115200,
                      bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                      parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                      stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                      timeout=0.25 )
while True:
    s = raw_input()
    if s:
        port.write( s + '\n' )
```

This works great - I can read the text coming through the port using an app like "Serial port terminal" or such.

Here is the sample "reader.py" that works find on another machine but fails immediately on mine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import serial

print( 'Opening port' )
port = serial.Serial( port='/dev/pts/10',
                      baudrate=115200,
                      bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                      parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                      stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                      timeout=0.25 )
while True:
    s = port.readline()
    if s:
        print( s )
```

Once I create the virtual port with the `socat` command and run "reader.py", I always get the exception immediately.  Any ideas what might have changed on my machine that would cause this failure?

System info:

```
~/temp$ uname -a
Linux alonghi-ubu 3.13.0-65-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 18:50:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~/temp$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

Comment: Serial port != serialization.

Comment: Ok... Any helpful ideas as to what might have caused this or how to trouble-shoot or fix?  Something changed on my Ubuntu system but I don't know how to figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 3.13.0.65 kernel breaks python serial communication. Try downgrading kernel to 3.13.0-63 and serial communication should work as before

Comment: Thank you!  ...and here's the details:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-trusty/+bug/1501345